SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')
I'm following the tutorial Build Python apps with Microsoft Graph and app-only authentication
I have already created its secret and IDs. I'm running it on a Mac M2.
Unfortunately when I run python3 main.py. I'm getting the following error:
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Cannot connect to host login.microsoftonline.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')]

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_aiohttp.py", line 348, in send
    raise ServiceRequestError(err, error=err) from err
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: Cannot connect to host login.microsoftonline.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x105a43390>


Are you trying to generate token using client certificate authentication?

I finally was able to solve it with this one liner after activating my virtual environment:
source venv_email_db/bin/activate
export SSL_CERT_FILE=$(python3 -m certifi)

Unfortunately, I have to do it every time.
